# Magento 2.3 setup page not Rendring on installation

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.3.2

I've setup WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) on my machine for development purpose with following stack.

```
Ubuntu : 18.04
PHP Version : 7.2
nginx : 1.14.0
mysql : 5.7
```

I've already installed all required prerequisites/PH Extensions of Magento 2.3.x

now I'm going to install Magento 2.3.2 but Magento not working properly.

I've extracted .tar file and execute following commands

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;  
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chown -R :www-data .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

while installing Magento setup page not rendering properly. Wordpress and CI works fine on the server it mean there is not the server configuration issue.

I'm not sure but i think there is no file permission issue, I'd installed magento 2.3.x so many times with Apache, this this is the first time I'm installing it with nginx

the output of magento setup page isn't completely blank kindly please visit URL

```
Output: https://snipboard.io/CfRilJ.jpg
Sourcecode: https://snipboard.io/vicz3S.jpg
```

Comment: what do you see in network & javascript tab while reloading the setup page?

Comment: kindly please check these screenshots 1. https://snipboard.io/0HR7an.jpg
2. https://snipboard.io/j8fe5m.jpg

Comment: It seems like you have misconfigured your webserver. Do you use Apache or Nginx?

Comment: this is first time i'm using nginx so may be you are right but i've no idea how to solve.

Comment: It's better to create a separate virtual host for your instance. I will help you configuring this in answer.

Comment: great, Thank you! i really appropriate you! kindly please instruct me.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use WLS (Ubuntu 18.04), I suppose that you know how to do these inside WSL terminal (bash).

Create a file with path `/etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2` to create a new virtualhost configuration.

```
$ sudo touch `/etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2`
```

Edit `/etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2` to match your Magento 2 configuration. For example, configuring the Magento 2 root path.

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
   server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name magento2.local; # this is a domain name for your Magento 2 instance, change this to match your need
   set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento; # this is your Magento 2 root path, change this to match your need
   include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample; # the nginx.conf.sample is located in your Magento 2 root directory, change the path to where your Magento 2 root directory is located
}
```

Create a symlink of that file to Nginx's `sites-enable` directory to enable that virtualhost.

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Add this line inside `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1 magento2.local # you should change the domain name if you change the domain name part in Nginx configuration created before
```

Restart Nginx

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

Open your Magento 2 setup again, it should work now.

Comment: I've followed your instruction but getting same problem but this time 403 instead of 404 in network. and angular issue is remain same in console kindly please check https://snipboard.io/bnpYgH.jpg

Comment: do you put the right paths (both of `$MAGE_ROOT` and `include`) inside `server {}`?